# Output dataset as collection of .csv files, .zip not an option C#

Tags: c#, file-io, zip

I have produced a solution in a C# web app that runs a report which returns a DataSet containing 9 Datatables.

The tables are linked with many-to-many relationships, and the purpose of the report is to produce a snapshot of the progress on records contained in the tables for anyone point in time.

This dictates that all 9 tables are queried at once, as querying the tables individually at different times will mean that the results dont match up between tables.

I was returning the 9 csv files in a zip file, which worked fine in development. However, in the organisation I am working for a lot of user's machines are very limited and we cannot rely on them having winzip or some other archiving software, and as such I have been told to find an alternative solution.

So far, the problems I have come up against are:

1. All 9 datatables must be produced from the same query, which rules out giving users the option to run the report against tables individually as the results may not match up if they are run at different times of the day.
2. I can only return one file at a time to the browser, which stops me returning the collection of csv files unzipped.
3. I did think about returning the data as separate tabs on an excel workbook, however some of the results have leading zeros, which will be trimmed off when they are loading into the worksheet.

It would be great if anyone knew of an obvious solution I'm missing?

Comment: Are some of the computers running a Windows OS older than XP? All Windows computers >=XP can handle ZIP files

Comment: No but there are some local restrictions that have disabled zip apparently

Comment: Are you using a database? How about creating a record for each time the report is run, and storing the data for each report in the database. Then any exisiting report can be selected, and the data from each table linked to that report downloaded individually as CSV files. This way the files would all be in sync for the selected report.

Comment: Thanks WraithNath, I was hoping to avoid trying to manage something like that across all users, multiple running of the report etc, but my options are extremely limited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using DotNetZip, you can zip and unzip files like so:

```
using Ionic.Zip;

namespace ConsoleApplication23
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Zip your files like so
            ZipFile x = new ZipFile();
            x.AddFile(@"C:\myFile");
            x.AddFile(@"C:\mySecondFile");
            x.Save(@"c:\myZipFile.zip");

            //Unzip like so
            ZipFile y = ZipFile.Read(@"c:\myZipFile.zip");

            foreach (ZipEntry e in y)
            {
                e.Extract(@"c:\test", ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this JMK. If I have understood this correctly, this will save a zip file directly onto the users C:\ drive? If so, how will they then unzip it if they have no archiving software?

Comment: I wonder if it would be possible to do what you have said here, and then use something like DotNetZip to then extract the .zip file on the C:\ drive? I'll have a look into it

Comment: Ah ok, I was working under the assumption you didn't want to use any third party libraries, if not then DotNetZip make this a lot easier!

Comment: Sorry I didnt make that clear, we already have a reference to DotNetZip in our project I can use it in this scenario

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can zip and unzip files entirely in your .Net program, regardless of what restrictions are placed on the users computer, as long as they are allowed to run your program and have read/write access to the directory you are working in